# Android: App screenshot preview in task list is blank?

Tags: android, android-homebutton, tasklist

In Android when you hold down the home button you can bring up a task list of your recent apps. And each "card" in the task list should have a preview of the app. However, this time I opened the task list and the previews were blank (except for the app title).

I had the phone Settings in the task list and every time I would tap on the task and try to open it in would close immediately.

I also had this app I was developing and when I tapped on the task to open the app my `RecyclerView` wasn't showing anything, when it should be.

I also was playing AngryBirds 2, so was it that Android had silently killed those apps for memory? If so, does `onCreate()` of the killed apps get called again when this happens?

Edit: I just noticed if you close an app too quickly when it's transitioning to an `Activity` you can get a blank preview.

Edit 2: So to answer my question, after referencing the Activity lifecycle diagram this is what I found. When another application needs memory, the app's process will be killed and when the user navigates back to the app, onCreate() will be called again. However, that doesn't explain why I couldn't reopen the Settings. And I have no idea how to reproduce this weird behavior!

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some debugging, I found out that Android did indeed kill my app because it needed memory. When you resume to your app however, `onCreate` will be called with a `savedInstanceState` that is `NOT null`. I had some logic that required `savedInstanceState` to be null and therefore my `RecyclerView` wasn't populated.

To recreate this scenario of Android killing my app I had to open a ton of apps lol. Is there way I can reproduce Android killing my app without opening all those apps? Hm...

Comment: Is this an answer or a question? Force stop might work.